# If item in each list?

Tags: python

How can I determine if a string is in each of a list of lists? For example:

```
listEven = ["0", "2", "4", "6", "8"]
listOdd = ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9"]
listPrimes = ["2", "3", "5", "7"]

listOfLists = ["listOdd", "listPrimes"]
if "9" in each(listOfLists):
    print("Math is broken")
else:
    print("Good, 9 is still not prime")
```

Basically, is there a function that checks if something is in every list in a list of lists?

Comment: Come on, learn some python basics first.

Comment: listOfLists is a list of two strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't use quotes here. Instead declare the list of lists as:

```
listOfLists = [listOdd, listPrimes]
```

Perhaps it would be better to use ints instead of strings as list elements as well (i.e. `3` and not `"3"`).

To answer your question, you can use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all("9" in l for l in listOfLists):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a way to achieve what you are asking for:

```
listEven = ["0", "2", "4", "6", "8"]
listOdd = ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9"]
listPrimes = ["2", "3", "5", "7"]

listOfLists = [listEven, listOdd, listPrimes]

def findNumber(number, list):
    for lists in list:    
        if number in lists:
            print ('Found it')

findNumber('9', listOfLists)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with lists of lists is a pain and unnecessary in this case. The easiest way to do this is to simply combine the desired lists into one:

```
masterList = listOdd + listPrimes
```

Then it's just:

```
if number in masterList:
```

Now, this uses more memory and is slower than it needs to since some numbers are duplicated, and Python has to look at each item. So instead, use a set:

```
masterSet = set(listOdd) | set(listPrimes)
```

Then `if number in masterSet` is very quick.